# Update table using GUID

Tags: mysql, asp.net, guid

I am using MySQL with ASP.NET/VB. In a table I use `GUID` instead of `int` identifiers. All goes as planned until I try to update a specific row, where I get a syntax error in the statement below:

```
 Dim q As String = "UPDATE documents SET date_document = @date_document, document_type = @document_type, sender = @sender, receiver = @receiver, description = @description, document_number = @document_number, pages = @pages, handled_date = current_timestamp, handled_user_id = @handled_user_id, error_code = @error_code) WHERE id = @id"
```

My `GUID` parameter:

```
.Parameters.Add("@id", MySqlDbType.Guid, 16).Value = myguid
```

And the error:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') WHERE id = '8873442f-2f0b-4372-ac08-8388220c6eca'' at line 1
```

Any ideas on what's going on?

Comment: What's the column type for 'id' ?

Comment: Hi, the type is varchar(64)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're chasing down the wrong issue. What character does your error syntax begin with? It starts off as ') Where id = ...

You're assuming it's the id. It's not. That works fine. The first character is a closing parenthesis. That's the clue. There is no opening parenthesis. Remove the ) because you don't need it with an update statement.

Comment: You are right! It was the parenthesis. Thank you for noticing!